# KDE Plasma dual monitor issue

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde

I installed kde plasma from terminal in my Ubuntu 22.04 distribution to try KDE desktop environment.

Whenever I log into plasma my main screen gets stuck at the Ubuntu Booting logo while my secondary screen works normal.

The problem gets resolved and dual screen works properly after pulling out the hdmi cable and then plugging it back in but I don't want to keep pulling out and in every time I boot.

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 with GDM-3 display manager.

When I screenshot while my main screen is stuck, the screenshot shows the screen as it should (There isn't Ubuntu logo stuck on my screenshot)

I use Nvidia gtx 1050 as gpu and intel i7 7700hq as cpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using ubuntu 22.04 with GDM-3 display manager.

By default, yes, KDE Plasma has many compatibility issues with GNOME's GDM display manager. This is why KDE recommends using non-GDM display managers, primarily SDDM (as used in Ubuntu-based [KDE Neon](https://neon.kde.org)) when working with the Plasma desktop.

Sure you may lose some GNOME-exclusive features in GDM (e.g. unread notification counts), but you may switch between GNOME (if it is still installed) and Plasma after you log out, the same way as in GDM.